# Auth0 rules - read metadata from getUser()

Tags: javascript, php, auth0

I'm using Auth0 rules to add some info to the user profile. 
When reading the profile from the web app:

```
$userInfo = $auth0->getUser();
```

the data added by the rules does not seem to be there.
Is there another method to get the metadata?

```
$auth0->getUserMetadata();
```

is there but returns 'undefined index'

Answer (score 0):

Aha, it appears that you need to call

```
auth0.users.updateUserMetadata(user.user_id, user.user_metadata)
```

in the rule .js before the getUserMetadata() will return metadata to your app.